# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Lang.IAppandeble' to 'Java.Lang.StringBuilder'

Tags: c#, android, mono, append, xamarin

I am getting this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Lang.IAppandeble' to 'Java.Lang.StringBuilder'."

I am not sure what is happening.

Here is the code

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder ();
char a = Convert.ToChar("x = ");
char b = Convert.ToChar(e.Values [0]);
char c = Convert.ToChar(", y = ");
char d = Convert.ToChar(e.Values [1]);
char t = Convert.ToChar(", z = ");
char f = Convert.ToChar(e.Values [2]);
text = text.Append (a).Append (b).Append (c).Append (d).Append (t).Append (f); //error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty wrong. `Convert.ToChar` returns a single character. You can't convert a whole string to a single character.

Try this instead:

```
var text = string.Format("x = {0}, y = {1}, z = {2}",
                         e.Values[0], e.Values[1], e.Values[2]);
```

---

The compiler error you are getting comes from the fact that you seem to be using the `StringBuilder` class exposed by Xamarin. This wraps the `StringBuilder` available in the Android SDK.
But that's not what you want to be using in C# code. In C# code you want to use [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been programming for a long time. So I'm still a noob.

Comment: Originally, this is where I got the code: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/accelerometer/get_accelerometer_readings  But it gave me "cannot convert float to char"

Comment: @JoachimVelzel: Compare that with what you have. For instance, there is no `Convert.ToChar` there.

Answer (score 0):

First, this code will cause a run time exception for `a`, `c`, and `T`; of course code execution will stop at `char a = Convert.ToChar("x = ");` line complaining about that

`"x = "` must be one character only, ex: `"x"`, and so on

Second, the append won't give you an error!, it will append the string normally.

Third, your exception seems to be Java related, and you are tagging the question with c#, so ?